# What does IE mean by saying "'console' is undefined"?

Tags: web-development, development-process, browser

I like IE's persnicketiness (the debugging tools that take you right to your code is even more user-friendly than what I've found in F12 Chrome Dev Tools), but why does it say, "'console' is undefined" re: this line of jQjuery:

```
console.log("entered submit button click");
```

How could *console* be undefined? Neither Chrome nor Firefox complain about it...

And ironically, IE shows me this error message where? In the "Console" tab! Shirley it couldn't be case-sensitive, and it expects "Console.log"?

BTW and anyway, I'm impressed with IE's F12 tools; I wonder if it's "The Avis Effect" at work - they were #5 (among Browsers) and have thus begun fighting like a rabid wolverine to claw and scratch their way upwards?

Comment: IE does not automatically create a console object.  The debugging tools need to be open (or have been open) before the object is created.  This little gotcha has caught many developers over the years.  To get around it, make a wrapper function that checks for the validity of the console object before writing to it, or create a dummy console object that contains the methods you use.  But, this is likely off topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Stack Overflow - where it will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned the console object is not guaranteed to exist in IE.  It only gets "created" when the debug tools are opened.

I wrote a small lib that handles this and other cross browser console issues such as console.time support in IE and console.profile inconsistencies.

https://github.com/pllee/counsell

For example `counsell.time` will never throw an error in IE, with or without the debug tools open.

Comment: If you are really Pat Lee of the Packers, this would not only be interesting, but quite a coincidence, as I have been a Packers fan for over 40 years.

Comment: @ClayShannon No I don't play for the Packers anymore ;).   I was almost able convince a bartender in Brookfield that I did though.

Comment: I lived in Brookfield a decade ago; also lived in Oconomowoc for 11 years; Carmel Valley, California now.

Comment: Actually, it's been 13 years ago since I lived in Brookfield (1997-2000).

Comment: @ClayShannon it is a nice place, lots of Packers fans :)